# Update table : Dataset or LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2005, dataset

I am trying to perform insert/update/delete operations on a SQL table based on the input csv file which is loaded into data table from an web application. Currently, I am using DataSet to do CRUD operations but would like to know if there will be any advantages of using LINQ over DataSet. I am assuming code will be reduced and more strongly typed but not sure if I need to switch to LINQ. Any inputs appreciated.

**Edit**

It is not a bulk operation, CSV might contain 200 records max.

Comment: Once you've decided to do it wrong, how tends to be an irrelevance. You should get your dbms to do this.

Comment: If the database is SQL Server, you can use SSIS for bulk operations, for instance.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, it is modification to the existing application. So I am restricted with technologies that I can use here. I know SSIS is ideal for this, but its not an option here. Since its SQL Server 2005, I can't even pass table parameter.

Comment: Why do you need a DataSet or LINQ to update 200 rows? This is something you could do with Table-Valued Parameters quite easily (and much more efficiently, I'd imagine, as well).

Comment: Yes, that would be better option but Table Valued Parameter is not supported in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the version tag. Does LINQ even support SQL Server 2005? How well? Why are you still using such an old version? Will you continue to use it when support is retired (which is coming up pretty soon)?

Comment: Yes it does but don't know why they are still using 2005.

Comment: Actually mainstream support for 2005 SP4 ended December 13, 2011.

Comment: If I had to do it on DB, other option I can think of is passing it as XML data type and retrieve into temp table and perform CRUD operations. Does it work?

Comment: Reformat the csv to a bulk insert to some permanently temporary table. Once it's in the db then it's just 2/3 queries to sync up the converted csv and the target table. Multiple users doing at the same time would be an issue, but that doesn't seem to be relevant from what you've posted.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, thanks for the input. Yes, it works too. I think I need to call stored proc. after bulk copy to process and delete the records. I think XML data type is reasonable, it is allowing me to write logic in single stored procedure without temporary storage mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [LumenWorks CSV reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) which is very fast.  It has it's own API for extracting data, using the IDataReader interface.  Here is a brief example taken from codeplex.com.  I use it for all my CSV projects, as it's very fast at reading CSV data.  I was surprised at how fast it actually was.

If you were to go from a reader like this, you're essentially going from a data reader API and as such, would probably work with a data table more easily (you could create a DataTable matching the result set and easily copy data over matching column to column).

A lot of updates can be slower with LINQ, depending on whether you are using Entity Framework or something else, and what flavor you are using.  A DataTable, IMHO would probably be faster.  I had issues with LINQ and change tracking with a lot of objects (if you are using attached entities, not using POCOs).  I've had pretty good performance taking a CSV file from Lumenworks and copying it to a DataTable.

Comment: Yes, I came across this open source library and also another one, FileHelpers. It will certainly help me to parse CSV into data table but my problem here is how to perform CRUD operations on a table based on the parsed data.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I didn't address that.  I'll update my response above.

Comment: thanks for updating the answer. So, it seems LINQ is not worth considering. I am considering passing list as XML data type over DataSet because it removes lot of code from web application and also provides better error handling. Using, DataSet, if there is error in any of insert/update/delete, it is failing.

Comment: I am marking it as an answer as it includes all details which might be helpful for others.